# Tomcat7 websocket libs clash with JHipster's

Tags: java, dependencies, tomcat7, jhipster, spring-websocket

I have built backend application with JHipster 4.14.1 which uses websockets.
I need to deploy this app to the Tomcat7x.

Application deploys successfully, but when I try to connect to it's websocket endpoint I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer
```

For what I found as solutions I have tried to add

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

but that didn't help.

Help appreciated.

Comment: JHipster embeds Undertow server and its dependencies, have you excluded them?

Comment: I have marked `spring-boot-starter-undertow` as provided and did not help